# Android studio missing "Order a translation" button

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am following this tutorial and need to have my UI text fields translated to various languages to improve application reach. But I can't seem to find the "Order a translation" button that I need to get language translators.

Please note I am note yet duely registered as a developer perhaps that's is why I can't see that button.

My Android Studio:

[image]

Instructor's Android Studio note the button to the top-right:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google documentation:

> Note that this is a payed service, delivered by third party localization service > providers. To use the service, developers need a Google Wallet account for payment.

This may be the problem.

Comment: Thought as much! When I sign up then if only the tutorial had said so.